# How do I make removing reactions edit a message in discord.py?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a command that has 5 different embeds, and I wanted to add 4 reactions, one for each embed that isn't the inital one, and then removing a reaction would edit the message back to the first one, but removing a reaction isn't doing anything. How do I fix that? Here's the code:

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
  if user != client.user: #client.user being the bot
    if reaction.emoji == NG:
      await message.edit(embed=embed1)
    if reaction.emoji == EE:
      await message.edit(embed=embed2)
    if reaction.emoji == SD:
      await message.edit(embed=embed3)
    if reaction.emoji == DD:
      await message.edit(embed=embed4)
@client.event
async def on_reaction_remove(reaction, user):
  if user != client.user:
    await message.edit(embed=embed0)
```

Comment: Can you improve your question? It's really bad and it's difficoult to understand what you really need.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Found out how to do this, instead of using

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_remove(reaction, user):
  if user != client.user:
    await message.edit(embed=embed0)
```

I used

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(reaction):
    await message.edit(embed=embed0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Message1 = await ctx.send(embed = Embed(description = ""))
```

You can do like this, and Message1 will be a discord.Message object.

```
await Message1.edit(embed = NewEmbed)
```

And like this you will edit the message.

```
await Bot.add_reaction(Message1, emoji)
```

Like this you will react to your own message.
This should work.

Comment: I already know how to make the message be edited when adding reactions, I want to know if I can make it be edited when removing reactions

Comment: Nope, it just doesn't do anything when I remove a reaction